# How to scale on curved surface

Tags: mesh

I want to inset and then scale the mesh on a curved surface. How do I do that? Since i cannot inset beyond a certain point. I want the scale to conform with the shape of the original shape. It should just slide like skin along the surface. How can I do it?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your current topology it seems complicated, also you should tell what is your final goal, but you could redo something similar this way:

Create a cube, create a UV sphere, give your cube a *Boolean* modifier (*Intersect* mode) with the sphere as boolean *Object*:

[image]

Apply the modifier, select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*, in the *Operator* box set the *Merge Distance* to 0.05. There are still some isolated vertices, remove them with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>:

[image]

Deselect the flat faces and inset:

[image]